# Vue.js component's data values are not defined when using {{interpolation}}

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pug

I'm trying to define a basic Vue.js component with pug :

```
script(type="text/x-template" id="my-design")
  div(:class="{active: active}")
    input(type="text", name="name", v-model="d.name", placeholder="Name")
    span {{d.name}}


script.
  var myDesign = Vue.component('my-design', {
    template: '#my-design',
    data: function(){
      return {
        active: true,
        d:{
          name: 'test', 
          _id:'test'
        }, 
      }
    },
  });
```

in the parent template i call it like this:

```
  include ../components/myDesign

  div
    my-design
```

i get this error : 
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: d is undefined"

if i remove the line `span {{d.name}}` it's ok , the input value is set to d.name value so the v-model instruction is working, and the active class is set too.

Comment: I think there's a typo: `sideContent.myDesigns.atcive` should be `sideContent.myDesigns.active`

Comment: There's something wrong with how you are passing the `d` variable in your `res.render` statement. Without seeing that it won't be possible to help you find the solution.

Comment: @muka.gergely yes i've corrected my question.

Comment: @Graham after more testing i've simplified my question. what do you mean by 'passing variable to res.render'  ? it is a vue.js component, i think vue.js is made to handle that . isn't it ?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using the pug vue.js add-in, which is why I assumed you're using server-side pug.  https://github.com/jaeming/vue-cli-plugin-pug